Anchoring Slam generated map to UTM coordinates
I generated a map of my world using SLAM and now I want to use GPS to localize in that particular map.
I am finding it confusing on how to anchor this slam map to the UTM coordinates?
As far as I've understood the SLAM mapping puts the location of the map frame to the starting position of the robot and then outputs the x,y location of the bottom left corner of the corresponding png file in the yaml file. I would specifically like to have this bottom left corner set as the map frame in the UTM coordinates and have the navsat transform publish the utm->map tf (or the other way round) and then have my robot localize itself within that map.
This is to be able to use generated costmap and planners of the existing stack along with gps localization. What I know so far is that people use an empty map file to trick the stack and do the same thing as mentioned above.
what purpose does wait_for_datum and 'datum' parameters of the navasat transform node serve? Does providing a datum set the map frame to that particular location?
